# How to identify a red flag using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, hsv, identification

How to identify a red flag using opencv in Python?
I can identify a red flag using threshold but it is only useful when the background is the same color. How to identify the red flag in different background using open cv2?  Or how to get the exact HSV number of a color in a image and than identify it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not extracting the **red** channel and identify it by thresholding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) to convert your image to HSV. When you have it in HSV you can split it into separate channels with [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) and threshold the hue, saturation and value to find a region with the color you are looking for. The number of pixels matching your criteria can be counted by [countNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) to see if the flag is present or not.